# Active Users in application from Active Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I would like to display a list of active users on my application's dashboard.

All of my users are employees and access the application through their Active Directory credentials.

I have used UserPrincipal to get the details of the current user, but can this be done for all of the current users?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for all "enabled" UserPrincipal 
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeUser.IsEnabled = true;

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.